# Load AFNetworking result array in UIPickerView, but synchronous calls aren't supported

Tags: ios, afnetworking, synchronous, ibaction

I have `AFNetworking` Webservice Call  which will return "List of Services". I am just initiating this Web Service Call when user hits `UIPickerView`. Its in

```
- (IBAction)selectServices:(UIControl *)sender;
```

as it is not supporting synchronous call ( tried `[operation waitUntilFinished]` and adding in queue also), I am unable to load services after async call.
 @Matt suggested not to make synchronous in `AFNetworking`. But if there is any way to do that, it will help my cases. What shall I do? Suggestion Please...

Comment: You really don't need it to be synchronous. You never do.

Comment: You don't want it to be synchronous.  You want it to refresh the picker view once the web service returns, or possibly not display the picker at all until the web service returns.